# How To const/let/var Multiple const/let/var in one const/let/var

Tags: javascript

Hey i wanna ask how to const all const in one like

```
const a = "a"
const b = "b"
const c = "c"
```

can I just
`` const all = `a,b,c` `` ??

Comment: you can separate variable names and their initializers with commas, so `const a = "a", b = "b", c = "c";`

Comment: What is the end goal here? Smells a bit like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), maybe you just need an array or an object.

Answer (score 1):

#### Multi-variable assignments

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
const a="a", b="b", c="c"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use destructing assignment

```js
const [a, b, c] = ["a", "b", "c"]

console.log(a, b, c)
```